# Android SQLite Exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using a SQLite database to store some data. When retrieving I get an exception. I have no clue what i'm doing wrong. That's why i'm asking this question.

Database code:

```
//Creating the database
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+garbageTable+" (" +colID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +colName+ " TEXT, "+colInterval+ " INTEGER, " +colDate+ " INTEGER, " +colImage+ " INTEGER)");
}

//Insert some data
public void insertGarbageObject(GarbageObject g){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colName, g.name);
    cv.put(colInterval, g.dayInterval);
    cv.put(colDate, g.date.getTimeInMillis());
    cv.put(colImage, g.image);
    db.insert(garbageTable, colID, cv);

    db.close(); 
}

//Read all inserted data
public ArrayList<GarbageObject> getGarbageObjects(){
    ArrayList<GarbageObject> garbageObjects = new ArrayList<GarbageObject>();

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+garbageTable,new String [] {});
    for(int i = 0; i<cur.getCount(); i++){
        GarbageObject g = new GarbageObject(c.getString(R.string.naam));
        g.ID = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(colID));//Exception occurs!
        g.name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(colName));//Exception occurs!
        g.dayInterval = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(colInterval));//Exception occurs!
        g.date.setTimeInMillis(cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(colDate)));//Exception occurs!
        g.image = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(colImage));//Exception occurs!


        garbageObjects.add(g);
    }
    cur.close();
    db.close();

    return garbageObjects;
}
```

My logcat:

```
10-14 17:35:58.356: W/dalvikvm(18570): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f27680)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{robin.garbagereminder/robin.activities.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at robin.garbagereminder.DatabaseHelper.getGarbageObjects(DatabaseHelper.java:59)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at robin.activities.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:88)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at robin.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
10-14 17:35:58.356: E/AndroidRuntime(18570):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: FYI, logcat is better as a code block than a blockquote. I edited the Question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the SQliteCursor correctly, it works this way:

```
if (cur != null ) {
    if  (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String tmp = c.getString(R.string.naam)
            ...
        }while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

In your Example you do nothing with the Cursor Object, and also nothing with the Cursor. Adding `cur.moveToNext()` at the beginning of the for-Loop will be exactly the same, but cleaner version is the while-loop.

Comment: Thanks mate, I indeed forgot cur.moveToPosition(i);